# Why does the US not have AIREPs?

Tags: air-traffic-control, airline-pilot

After looking into aircraft report data at Aviation Weather Center, I realized that PIREP is usually reported inside of US; on the other hand, AIREP is typically reported outside of US. I was wondering if there is any specific/particular reason why AIREP is not available at US territory?

Answer (score 2):

Apples and oranges. A PIREP is a report of current weather conditions at a specific location. An AIREP is primarily a position report, required of some aircraft that are not under radar control. Whereas the primary purpose of a PIREP is to report unusual weather conditions or things like turbulence and are not mandatory, AIREP's are in many cases mandatory and weather information in Section 3 is optional.

Comment: Thanks Juan Jimenez for your answer! Based on your comments, I am guessing that AIREP was reported outside of US because aircraft was not under the radar control? In other words, AIREP is not necessarily reported in US territory because it's usually under radar control inside of US?

Please let me correct if I am wrong. Eventually, I might want to obtain wind information reported by pilots inside of US.

Comment: AIREPS are not used in the US because all aircraft *can* be under radar control if need be. But if you are traveling from Florida to Puerto Rico, a US territory, you may not always be in positive radar contact, so you may use them, because you may have to prove you did not make any intervening stops for customs and immigration purposes.